# Tsql Update Table with other table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two table sql

I want to update table A  with data from table

my issu is that

if (element exist update else update)

table a

- clubid |  memeber
- 1   |100
- 2   |150

table b

- clubid |  memeber
- 1   |200
- 9   |150
- 6   |50

I want table a will update like :

- clubid 1 = > updated
- clubid 9 and Clubid 6 = > will be insert

at the end

table a will be like that

- clubid |  memeber
- 1   |200
- 2   |150
- 9   |150
- 6   |50

I can t figure out how to do it can you please help me

Answer (score 1):

Two separate statements would do it:

```
UPDATE TableA SET TableA.Member = TableB.Member 
FROM TableB 
WHERE TableA.ClubID = TableB.ClubID

INSERT INTO TableA
SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE ClubID NOT IN ( SELECT ClubID FROM TableA )
```

Comment: @samit glad it helped. If you liked it, please accept it as and aswer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Merge`.

```
merge tableA trg
using tableB src on trg.clubid=src.clubid
when matched then
update set trg.member=src.member
when not matched by trg then
insert(clubid,member)
values (src.clubid,src.member);
```

Comment: Merge has some potential hazards: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/